# meaning of "expenses' in "hand in expenses"

Tags: word-meaning

Does it make sense to say "hand in expenses," as in "Please hand in the expenses by Friday"?

I think the object of "hand in" is some sort of document, but "expenses" does not refer to documents.

Comment: Could you provide the whole sentence? The meaning of "hand in expenses" is unclear.

Comment: @CowperKettle  It's not an uncommon expression in business, where company employees are required to keep track of *business expenses* that they have paid themselves, so they can be reimbursed (such as business trips, office expenses, mileage, etc.).  These employees are expected to "hand in" their expenses to Accounting, usually on a specified timetable.

Comment: "Hand in the expenses" is fine, but I think more common is, *"Hand in **your** expenses (by Friday)"*.  Unless perhaps the expenses are for something like a project, in which case it's usually specified, *"Please hand in **the expenses for the project** by Friday"*.

Comment: In Britain, people found to have falsified claims for expenses are very often said to have "fiddled their expenses".

Comment: The verb **hand in** has come to mean "submit".  Do you understand? Oh, sorry, that might not make sense to you. After all, what are you standing under?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo The question really concerns the meaning of "expenses," not "submit." It turns out that "expenses" is used to refer to something concrete like receipts, but this sense is not recorded in major dictionaries.

Comment: Actually you asked whether the combination **hand in** with **expenses** "make[s] sense" because you think "the object of *hand in* is some sort of document".  The verb **hand in** has come to mean "to submit, to return" and it accepts a broad range of objects, both tangible and intangible,  including rental vehicles and electronic submissions.

Comment: How would you define "expenses" in this context then?

Answer (score 2):

I would add some qualification to it.

"Please hand in the expenses by Friday" would really feel better as "Please hand in *your* expenses by Friday", or "Please hand in all expenses for xyz project by Friday".

It's the type of construction a native speaker wouldn't even notice that words or ideas had even been missed out, so to break it down a bit...

"Hand in" - equates to "give to me" [or the person tasked with the job of collating & reimbursing business expenditure.] If it was a 3rd person, they would probably qualify it with their name or title, unless everyone in the conversation was already perfectly aware of to whom.

"Expenses" is really "the receipts for your business expenditure". You can't really give anyone your expenses; they just need the proof of those expenses.

Comment: You are the only one to rightly point out the problem that puzzles learners; "expenses" is used in the sense of "receipts," but this is not recorded in any dictionaries.

Comment: @Apollyon To me, as someone who is used to submitting "expenses" every month, **expenses** is more than just receipts - it's mainly a report that tabulates all expenses for the month, with the receipts added as documentation.  And this is what's common in business situations: using a plain noun to mean "**report** of [noun]."  For example, "Bob presented the sales results," does not mean that Bob presented a pile of money, even though money is literally the result of sales. It means that Bob presented a **report** of the sales results.